# MongoDb - command drop requires authentication

Tags: mongodb

I have the following command

```
mongo clean_collection.js --host localhost --username root --password example
```

Clean_collection.js file contains:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("MyDb");
var myColl = db.getCollection('MyCollection');
myColl.drop();
```

But MongoDb returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("22d094e1-fb65-46c8-a9e6-386c1678c680") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
2020-07-15T10:33:00.787-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: drop failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "command drop requires authentication",
"code" : 13,
"codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.drop@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:696:15
```

I'm also using MongoDb .NET Driver and I can drop the collection withou any problems with using .NET driver.

Comment: Do you connect to the .NET driver the same? Do you not provide user/password there by any chance?

Comment: @noam In .NET I'm using the connectionstring. it's passed as a parameter in MongoClient constructor. The connectionstring is "mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017"